# which port is used to gossip in akka actor cluster by the cluster members?

Tags: actor, akka-cluster

I am trying to debug an issue where cluster island are getting formed. 
checking if there is an network issue.

which port is used to gossip in akka actor cluster by the cluster members ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your configuration - it's the TCP port that you set up Akka to listen on. For more details refer to [Cluster configuration docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-usage.html) (see the `port` and `seed-node` values).

**Broader hints on cluster partitions:**
If you ended up having a cluster partition in an Akka cluster it most likely means you're using the `auto-downing` feature. It's not recommended for production use, as it's rather fleaky - it relies on a simple timeout based mechanism. For more advanced downing mechanisms you can look into using the [Split Brain Resolver](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/rp-15v09p01/scala/split-brain-resolver.html) commercial tooling, or build a downing mechanism yourself which would hook into external monitoring infrastructure (we've seen a number of teams do this).

An interesting thought to keep in mind is that perhaps you do not need auto-downing at all, and when leaving the cluster with a node you can do so cleanly by issuing `Cluster.leave(address)` in the code.

Comment: Thanks Konrad . Seems like better to turn off auto-downing for now